# Is Nylon RF transparent?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, material-science, radio-frequency

I was doing a research on which type clothes blocks the Radio frequency.  Please also list the experiments which can be performed to determine such clothes/ materials.

Comment: What experiments can you think of yourself?

Comment: @Pieter Any type experiment which can performed at home or in colleges.

Comment: Nylon is one of the lowest conductive loss RF materials in use, so it is as "transparent" as possible. You can test this by placing a chunk of it in a microwave oven and measure its temperature rise over a given time against other materials of the same mass.

Comment: The only article of clothing that I know to block radio frequencies is the tin foil hat.

Comment: @Pieter lead-foil hats work well too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the loss tangents of common dielectrics.

http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/genesys200801/elements/substrate_tables/tablelosstan.htm

For nylon at 3 GHz the loss tangent is $1.2 \times 10^{-2}$.  This is actually pretty large (high loss) compared to polystyrene or teflon.  So it would seem to be decent absorber.  Nowadays I believe you can get metallic mesh cloth, which would reflect microwaves.  tin foil anyone? Anything wet would be a great absorber.  At these frequencies the standard measurement technique involves a VNA and a transmission  line.  This is tricky to do but if you have access to the equipment, maybe that's the way.  At microwave frequencies you can try cavity perturbation, but you need the cavity (test fixture).  I like @hyportnex's idea of just zapping in a microwave.  You could calibrate this with some known samples.  Might be easiest in that case to grind the teflon up into a powder that you can pack inside something of low loss (a quartz cuvette say) and then calibrate out the cuvette with water and a few other known materials.

By the way, if your college doesn't have a VNA, then you can in principle do everything with a function generator and an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist in RF, but I have a lot of experience with Nylon.  Nylon is hydrophilic and absorbs moisture from the air quickly. Two samples with different levels of water saturation will likely measure differently in a microwave heating test.